# Is the subscribe() method blocking?

Tags: java, project-reactor, publish-subscribe, blocking

I'm starting with Project Reactor and I cant understand why is this code infinitely prints "Hello" and never returns the `Disposable` object.

```
Flux<Object> flux = Flux.generate(sink -> sink.next("Hello"));
Disposable disposable = flux.subscribe(System.out::println);
disposable.dispose();
System.out.println("This doesn't print");
```

I thought that when it comes to call `subscribe()` method it must immediately return the `Disposable` object with which I can unsubscribe if I want. I know that code inside this `subscribe` method running in the same thread and if I substitute the `delayElements`method before the `subscribe` call then the code below will work because it runs in a separate daemon thread, so can any explain why does it stop at the `subscribe`method and not return `Disposable` and are there any ways to manage a subscription by calling the `subscribe` method? Is it possible to make it so that, by analogy with the `delayElements` method, this is executed in a separate thread and the result of calling the `subscribe` method returns `Disposable` immediately?

I couldn't find an answer specifically to this question. In all the examples that I saw there was either a finite data stream or the delayElements method was used.

Comment: add some stop logic and  stop emit source with  ```sink.complete```

Comment: @Peng but if this is a remote datasorce that i cant modify, how can I unsubscribe from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `subscribe()` is blocking in this particular scenario.

Reactor is [concurrency agnostic](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#schedulers) which means by default it doesn't enforce any threading/asynchronicity on you and executes the pipeline on the calling thread (in this particular case the main thread).

You can change this explicitly by using `subscribeOn` or `publishOn`, or implicitly by using some operators like `delayElements`.

```
Flux<Object> flux = Flux.generate(sink -> sink.next("Hello")).publishOn(Schedulers.parallel());
Disposable disposable = flux.subscribe(System.out::println);
disposable.dispose();
System.out.println("This doesn't print");
```